# How to make a pivot like sql result

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

How to convert this :

```
name sub    value
a   maths   4
b   science 5
a   history 3
c   computer1
c   english 4
b   computer5
c   history 3
a   science 8
b   maths   3
```

Into something like this :

```
name    maths   science history computer    english
a          4          8      3       5         NIL
b          3          5      NIL     NIL       NIL
c          NIL       NIL     3       1          4
```

I have made a query like this.

```
select @cols := group_concat(distinct replace('MAX(CASE WHEN sub = ''[val]''   then ''y'' ELSE ''n'' END) AS `[val]`', '[val]', sub))
from (select distinct sub from t) t;

set @sql = concat('select name, ', @cols,
                  ' from t group by name'
                 );

prepare st from @sql;
execute st;
deallocate prepare st;
```

In this code I used y or n values. But I need to replace it with corresponding values of a  specific column value

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: i am using mysql